# Is it possible to set a project-wide form theme for a Visual Basic WinForms project?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, themes

The project I'm working on is being made for a client in Visual Basic .NET, and was started some two or three years ago.  Since I was brought onto the project about six months ago, I've been trying to improve the workflow involved and one of the issues I've found is to do with the look and feel of the project.

It's been mandated that rather than using the default Windows styling, every form for the project use specific colors (white for the form backgrounds, white on red for buttons, things like that).  Up to now this has been handled by setting all of the properties manually each time a form is created, but that tends to mean a lot of tedious property setting each time a new form is created and it leads to a handful of forms not using the correct color scheme.

I'm thinking that there must be some easier way to handle this.  Researching it found me a few frameworks that let you use alternatives to the regular forms so that you can support complex theming, but the project's got hundreds of forms already and redoing them using a new framework would be a massive task (not to mention that the code is brittle and a lot of the application logic is in the front-end, so the odds of something breaking are pretty high).

Long story short: I want to know if there's some simple way to apply a theme that can be accessed project-wide in Visual Studio without it being necessary to set it every time a form is created.  I don't especially mind if it's not as simple as flipping a switch, but ideally it would be something that the old forms could be relatively easily retrofitted to use.

Comment: https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Skins/

Comment: does has the mandator have any training in UI design at all?

Comment: @C-PoundGuru: From what I can tell, DevExpress supplies an entirely separate set of controls, so updating our application to work with it would mean completely replacing hundreds of forms and their contents.  Like I said initially, I'm looking for something that would have a much lower impact (though I'm starting to think there's not really an option for that).

Comment: @Plutonix: of course not.  I doubt they'd be demanding that we use non-standard theming for a relatively standard window-based Windows application if they did.  

Edit: Just to clarify: the mandate comes from the client and they expect this color scheme to apply to absolutely all of their software, so it's not flexible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looked into this further, and from what I can tell there's not really any appropriate solution for the situation.  Would be glad to be proven wrong, but from what I can tell WinForms don't let you set an application-wide color scheme that it uses in place of the base theme defined for controls by the OS (probably for good reason), and the alternatives all involve using expensive libraries that require the use of entirely different control sets (meaning a lot of outright replacement of existing components).

Comment: Really?  Downvote with no reason why?  Would appreciate knowing if I was wrong here or something rather than just a random -1.